# highchart Axis values color

Tags: highcharts

I could not find the color value for each Axis in highcharts api documentation.
in other words I mean changing color of numbers at left/down side of each axis.

currently the configuration for Axis is like this:

```
xAxis: {
    lineColor: '#d8efe3',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    lineColor: '#d8efe3',
    gridLineColor: '#d8efe3',
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value / 1000 +'k';
        }
    }
},
```

edit:
there is nothing special about the chart, anyway assume the chart is as simple as this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/llexl/

Comment: a jsfiddle link would help to let others find a solution for you

Comment: I'm a little confused.... Can you also provide a pic showing exactly what you want to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the [`labels`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels).  Just change the [`style`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.style) for the `yAxis label`.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/BBCzm/1/)</kbd>

```
xAxis: {
    lineColor: '#d8efe3',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    labels: {
         style: {
             color: 'orange'
         },
         formatter: function() {
            return this.value / 1000 +'k';
         }
    },
    lineColor: '#d8efe3',
    gridLineColor: '#d8efe3',
    title: {
        text: null
    }
},
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Exactly! thanks.sorry for newbie question. i didn't thought it might be under labels!

Answer (score 1):

This should change x and y axis label colors to red.  I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
xAxis: {
  lineColor: '#d8efe3',
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: 'red'
      },
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
      }
    }
  }
},

yAxis: {
  lineColor: '#d8efe3',
  gridLineColor: '#d8efe3',
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  labels: {
    style: {
      color: 'red'
    },
    formatter: function() {
     return this.value / 1000 +'k';
   }
 }
```

},

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-style/)
[Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels)